# Existe-t-il un équivalent français de « crowdsourcing » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, finance

Le « crowdsourcing » est une technique qui consiste à récolter un gros volume d'information à partir de données fournies volontairement (mais parfois à son insu) par le grand public. Connaissez-vous un équivalent en français (ou un beau néologisme)? J'ai trouvé « approvisionnement par la foule » sur le site linguee, mais je trouve la formule assez lourde.

EDIT: les informations que je récolte sont des observations localisées. Par exemple, « j'ai vu un ours dans ma rue ». Cela peut-être une photo GPS partagée sur Flickr (avec des coordonnées GPS), ou des informations encodées par un promeneur sur un site Web spécifique (GBIF, Open Street Map…).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La traduction officielle créée par la « commission générale de terminologie et de néologie » et [publiée au Journal Officiel](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000029331922&dateTexte=&oldAction=dernierJO&categorieLien=id) est :

> Production participative

Dans les faits l'expression « financement participatif » est beaucoup plus usitée.

Comment: merci. dans mon cas ce n'est cependant pas un "crowdfunding" mais plutôt de la production. L'expression officielle me convient donc mieux.

Comment: Oui, "fincancement participatif" = crowdfunding, pas crowdsourcing.

Answer (score 1):

D'accord, *production participative* est maintenant le terme officiel. Mais d'après les mots *artisanat*, *bénévolat* et *partenariat* (tous associés à l'organisation du travail), il peut être raccourci à ***participat***.

Comment: Ca a l'avantage d'être en un seul mot et "ça sonne bien"(j'aime bien), mais je ne retrouve ce terme nulle part. Venez-vous de l'inventer ou l'avez vous déjà rencontré dans un texte de référence ?

Answer (score 0):

M'bolani !

J'utilise la formule "source de données généraliste spontanée" ! Attention de bien distinguer la représentation (donnée) de sa signification (information).

Merci pour vos commentaires !